# How to dynamically create a list of checkboxes from an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, list, checkbox

I've created a menu item list using an array by looping through each array item and assigning attributes accordingly.

Now I need to append a checkbox to each `li` item in the menu. What I did try is appending an input of type checkbox following by appending an input `li` tag. But this creates a menu list of input boxes.

**Question:**

How can you dynamically create a list of checkboxes from an array?

This is the current code I use in the script to create the menu:

```
    //Bind the country name list in sub menu
    var countries = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Argentina', 'Armenia'];
    var assetList = $('#assetNameMenu')
    $.each(countries, function(i)
    {
        var li = $('<li/>')
            .addClass('ui-menu-item')
            .attr('role', 'menuitem')
            .appendTo(assetList);
        var aaa = $('<a/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .text(countries[i])
            .appendTo(li);
        var input = $('<input/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .attr('role', 'checkbox')
            .appendTo(aaa);

    });



            <li>
                <a>All <span class="arrow">&#9660</span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu" id="assetNameMenu">
                   @* li elements created in script *@
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Which creates the following with no checkboxes:

[image]

The aim is instead to dynamically create a list of checkbox items:

```
               <li>
                    <a>Default <span class="arrow">&#9660</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu" id="assetNameMenu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Which creates this the below:

[image]

Comment: Your code is pretty much already doing that, you would just need to nest the checkbox array loop and amend the HTML accordingly

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you mean place another $.each inside the outer $.each? It seems my current implementation isn't converting the input's to type checkbox.

Comment: pretty sure `.attr('role', 'checkbox')` should be `.attr('type', 'checkbox')`

Comment: An interactive element (such as an `<input>`) cannot be nested within another interactive element (such as an `<a>`, or `<button>`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the correct type for *inputs* and change order:

```
$.each(countries, function(i)
    {
        var li = $('<li/>')
            .addClass('ui-menu-item')
            .attr('role', 'menuitem')
            .appendTo(assetList);

        var input = $('<input/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .attr('type', 'checkbox')
            .appendTo(li);

       var aaa = $('<a/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .text(countries[i])
            .appendTo(li);

    });
```

[image]

**Codepen**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLmQRp

***UPDATE***

For display:

```
.sub-menu {
 width: auto;
 [...]
}

.sub-menu li a { 
  text-align: left;
  [...]
}
```

**Example**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKxwoO

Comment: I tried the following http://hastebin.com/oxajoqepon.vhdl which is better but the checkboxes appear above each country name, instead of to the left of the name. Any ideas why?  http://picpaste.com/pics/options-MetOescC.1471265089.PNG

Comment: If you post the css too, we could see the display problem

Comment: Tried that but the checkboxes are staggered inline. http://picpaste.com/pics/option-cam7UI9t.1471265596.PNG This is a link to the css for that menu which I've set to display: inline-block - http://hastebin.com/ujavilofid.css

Comment: The above didn't work either, but adding property `float: left` to the li tag's CSS fixed the alignment. Feel free to add that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the type to `checkbox` : `.attr('type', 'checkbox')`

```
$.each(countries, function(i)
    {
        var li = $('<li/>')
            .addClass('ui-menu-item')
            .attr('role', 'menuitem')
            .appendTo(assetList);
        var aaa = $('<a/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .text(countries[i])
            .appendTo(li);
        var input = $('<input/>')
            .addClass('ui-all')
            .attr('type', 'checkbox')
            .appendTo(aaa);

    });
```